# I can't fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysqlite2'"

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, centos

I installed python3.9 and jupyter notebook on a brand new centos, but I got an error message saying "sqlite3 is missing". So I added sqlite3 and installed it again without deleting python3.9. However, I still get the message that sqlite3 is missing. What should I do?

```
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ sqlite3 --version
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

Comment: The error  message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`  is telling you that Python has been compiled without support for SQLite - the `_sqlite3` module has not been built.

Comment: How can I build it?

Comment: You need to follow the "recompile Python" steps in [Lseu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17561930/lseu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263476/5320906)

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with python 3.5 a long time ago, I could not run jupyter notebook. I was on ubuntu btw.

to resolve this :

```
conda install sqlite
conda install python=3.9
```

otherwise you can install libsqlite3-dev package and recompile Python.

So, from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get 
install libsqlite3-dev
```

And then, from the folder where you downloaded Python:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: sorry, I do not use conda. So no ubuntu.